# SQLite select in where clause

Tags: sqlite, select, where-clause

I have a query that returns a list codes.

```
SELECT cc.code FROM lotw l
                 LEFT JOIN CountryCode AS cc on cc.code = l.dxcc 
                 WHERE cc.code > ''  GROUP BY cc.Country
```

This works fine. Now I need to query the country table for codes that are not in the list that is sent back from the above query. so I tried the following:

```
SELECT code,country from CountryCode 
WHERE code !=  (SELECT cc.code FROM lotw l
                 LEFT JOIN CountryCode AS cc on cc.code = l.dxcc 
                 WHERE cc.code > ''  GROUP BY cc.Country)
```

However I get back all the records from the country code? I want all the country whose code is not in the sub query ?

Comment: That was it! if you put it as a answer I will mark it as the answer thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `NOT IN` instead of `!=`;

```sql
SELECT code,country from CountryCode 
WHERE code NOT IN (SELECT cc.code FROM lotw l
                   LEFT JOIN CountryCode AS cc on cc.code = l.dxcc 
                   WHERE cc.code > ''  GROUP BY cc.Country)
```